# Send userinp to batch from Java

Tags: java, batch-file, console

I have batch.cmd and I am running it in java by

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("batch.cmd");

and I do not know how can I enter (1-6).

I tried:
Console console = System.console();
but console is null

or

OutputStream outputStream = process.getOutputStream();
pos.write(49); //1
nothing happend

Could anyone help?

```
-----batch.cmd-----
echo start
:start
cls
set /p userinp=choose a number(1-6):
set userinp=%userinp:~0,1%
if "%userinp%"=="1" goto 1
if "%userinp%"=="2" goto 2
if "%userinp%"=="3" goto 3
if "%userinp%"=="4" goto 4
if "%userinp%"=="5" goto 5
if "%userinp%"=="6" goto 6
echo invalid choice
goto start
:1
echo 1
goto end
:2
echo 2
goto end
:3
echo 3
goto end
:end
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
BufferedWriter out 
    = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
out.write(option + "\n" );
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have full access to the source code of the cmd file, then the most obvious solution is to **not use** `SET /P` but to pass the option directly as a parameter to the batch file.

Change batch.cmd to ....

```
echo start
set inp=%1
if "%inp%"=="1" goto 1
if "%inp%"=="2" goto 2
echo invalid parameter
goto :eof
:1
echo 1
goto :eof
:2
echo 2
goto :eof
```

and invoke it with a single parameter of choice.